# can we call enable_irq() from workqueues?

Tags: kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

Is there any side-effects of calling `enable_irq()` from workqueues ? I see exceptions reported when this is done through workqueue.

```c
static void mmxx_irq_worker(struct work_struct *work)
{
    struct mmxx_data *mma = container_of(work, struct mmxx_data, accel_work);

    if (unlikely(read_and_report_abs(mmxx) != 0))
        dev_err(&mmxx_i2c_client->dev, "read_and_report failed\n");

    enable_irq(mmxx->irq);
}
```

```
[ 2029.755981] Exception stack(0xd51fbe70 to 0xd51fbeb8)
[ 2029.761718] be60: c09cee10 600b0113 00000001 00000000
[ 2029.771057] be80: c09cedc0 00000001 000002bf d508bb4c 000002d6 c09b3ac0 fffffffe d51fbec4
[ 2029.780426] bea0: d51fbec8 d51fbeb8 c00b6458 c06e5b28 400b0113 ffffffff
[ 2029.787841] r6:ffffffff r5:400b0113 r4:c06e5b28 r3:c00b6458
[ 2029.795379] [<c06e5b04>] (_raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x0/0x50) from [<c00b6458>] (__irq_put_desc_unlock+0x1c/0x40)
[ 2029.807189] [<c00b643c>] (__irq_put_desc_unlock+0x0/0x40) from [<c00b7c2c>] (enable_irq+0x54/0x7c)
[ 2029.817352] r5:000001e5 r4:c09cedc0
[ 2029.821990] [<c00b7bd8>] (enable_irq+0x0/0x7c) from [<c0357394>] (mmxx_irq_worker+0x1b8/0x238)
[ 2029.832061] r5:c0a1d8b4 r4:c0abb340
[ 2029.836700] [<c03571dc>] (mmxx_irq_worker+0x0/0x238) from [<c0063e70>] (process_one_work+0x134/0x4ac)
[ 2029.847442] [<c0063d3c>] (process_one_work+0x0/0x4ac) from [<c0064374>] (worker_thread+0x18c/0x3d8)
[ 2029.857757] [<c00641e8>] (worker_thread+0x0/0x3d8) from [<c0068df8>] (kthread+0x90/0x9c)
[ 2029.866790] [<c0068d68>] (kthread+0x0/0x9c) from [<c004c9f4>] (do_exit+0x0/0x81c)
[ 2029.875366] r6:c004c9f4 r5:c0068d68 r4:d699dec4
```

Comment: Show us the code of your workqueue handler.

Comment: @SamProtsenko: code updated , thanks

Comment: @SamProtsenko, remember that [stack snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) are for html, css, and javascript. You should remove their use on any other posts.

Comment: @gunr2171: thanks, wasn't sure it has to be removed.

Comment: Is there any warnings or notable output above of backtrace you provided? Maybe something like `enable_irq before setup/request_irq: irq ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workqueue is running in process context with IRQs enabled. So you should **not** do `enable_irq()` in workqueue handler, unless you disabled this IRQ earlier.

But you also shouldn't get that error. Probably `mmxx->irq` number is wrong or not requested. Pay attention to this line in your backtrace:

```
(__irq_put_desc_unlock) from (enable_irq)
```

It's happening in [enable_irq()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/irq/manage.c#L472) function:

```c
void enable_irq(unsigned int irq)
{
    unsigned long flags;
    struct irq_desc *desc = irq_get_desc_buslock(irq, &flags,
                                                 IRQ_GET_DESC_CHECK_GLOBAL);

    if (!desc)
        return;
    if (WARN(!desc->irq_data.chip,
             KERN_ERR "enable_irq before setup/request_irq: irq %u\n", irq))
        goto out;

    __enable_irq(desc, irq);

out:
    irq_put_desc_busunlock(desc, flags);
}
```

Where `irq_put_desc_busunlock()` is basically `__irq_put_desc_unlock()`.
Now you can see that the only way this chain is executed is when your `desc->irq_data.chip` is `NULL`. Also you should observe output like this in your backtrace:

```c
"enable_irq before setup/request_irq: irq %u\n"
```

From here I would say your `mmxx->irq` number you are passing to `enable_irq()` is wrong (`0`?) or this IRQ wasn't requested earlier. Try to check what exactly value you have in `mmxx->irq` and make sure have requested it before your workqueue handler is called first time.

Anyway, removing `enable_irq()` line from your code should fix the problem (as you probably don't really need to do this).

Comment: Is it possible to call enable_irq() from worker thread before calling request_irq()  or should we first allocate irq resource from request_irq and then call enable_irq()?

Comment: I think the best way would be to call `request_irq()` in your module init function, and start your work only after that (probably also in your module init function or somewhere else, but you must be sure you start your work **after** `request_irq`). This way you can eliminate your problem. Also I think you don't need to call `enable_irq()` at all: AFAIR interrupts are enabled in worker thread. Anyway, if you want to do so -- it should be harmless if you called `request_irq()` **before** calling `enable_irq()` for your IRQ number.